# Is there something better than System.Byte.Parse("0xAA") to get a single byte on F# and C# ?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, byte

So the question is on title

I'm making System.Byte.Parse("0xAA") but I feel like every-time compiler parse the string and I want just send this byte to compiler.

I know there are F# literals ( for example 86uy  ) but I want exactly hex mode. Maybe I can write AAuy but I can't understand how I can write it and 86uy in the same time. Because for example 11uy and 11uy (in hex mode) is different // correct me if I wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the context? What's wrong with just `0xAA` without parsing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to write a byte constant in hex, just do `0xAAuy`.

See [F# literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233193.aspx) from MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this?

```
// Valid C#
byte x = 0xAA;
```

(For the F# part, see Henning's answer.)

Comment: I though it isn't valid on C#. Thank you, but I still need F# answer then.

Comment: @神田翠: Just to assign a value to a variable? Have you tried `0xAAuy`?

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment? I've provided the C# part, and Henning's provided the F# part...

Comment: I had changed the question title and tag to F# after get the answer on C# part. My fault... I will back them to the question. @Downvoter, I hope you to undo this down-vote.